# PHP: use of preg_split()

Tags: php, regex

I have strings like this:

```
wh4tever_(h4r4ct3rs +syMb0|s! ASC
wh4tever_(h4r4ct3rs +syMb0|s! DESC
```

I don't know what the first characters are, but I know that they end by `' ASC'` or `' DESC'`, and I want to split them so that I get an array like:

```
array(
    [0] => 'wh4tever_(h4r4ct3rs +syMb0|s!'
    [1] => 'ASC' //or 'DESC'
)
```

I know it must be absolutely easy using `preg_split()`, but regexps are something I assumed I'll never get on well with...

Comment: Well... start assuming that you will. They're an invaluable cross-language tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression with `preg_split()`:

```
\s(?=(ASC|DESC))
```

**Explanation:**

- `\s` - match any whitespace character
- `(?=` - start of positive lookahead

  - `(ASC|DESC)` - `ASC` or `DESC`
- `)` - end of positive lookahead

**Visualization:**

[image]

**Complete:**

```
$str = 'wh4tever_(h4r4ct3rs +syMb0|s! ASC';
$arr = preg_split('/\s(?=(ASC|DESC))/', $str);
print_r($arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => wh4tever_(h4r4ct3rs +syMb0|s!
    [1] => ASC
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/145509)

Comment: What about `tghjgkuyy rtytry wh4tever_(h4r4ct3rs +syMb0|s! ASC` ?

Comment: That's the case. As I understand OP doesn't need anything before `what4ever` as he needs using regex.

Comment: @AmalMurali, thanks for the answer and the explanation mate! The part of the *positive ahead* is what I was missing...

Comment: @revo: I'm not sure I understand you. The OP states in the question: "*I don't know what the first characters are, but I know that they end by ' ASC' or ' DESC', and I want to split them*" — the regex doesn't care about what's in the beginning of the string. It only splits if the whitespace is followed by `ASC` or `DESC`.

Comment: @AmalMurali, it works perfectly fore me, I don't mind what's before ASC|DESC, I just want to split the string in exactly 2 pieces, one with ASC|DESC and another with all the rest...

Answer (score 3):

Try This,

```
$str = "wh4tever_(h4r4ct3rs +syMb0|s! ASC";
$str1 = "wh4tever_(h4r4ct3rs +syMb0|s! ASC";


$ar = preg_split('/(ASC|DESC)/i', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$ar1 = preg_split('/(ASC|DESC)/i', $str1, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

print_r($ar);
print_r($ar1);
```

output : 
Array ( [0] => wh4tever_(h4r4ct3rs +syMb0|s! [1] => ASC )
Array ( [0] => wh4tever_(h4r4ct3rs +syMb0|s! [1] => DESC )

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
\s(?=(A|DE)SC)
```

and split it.

As sshashank124, pointed, it is an extremely good tool which is language agnostic.

Comment: Some random downvoter I guess. My answer got downvoted as well.

Comment: @AmalMurali, yeah. Saw that. I just hate them ;)